# How to browser/explore public jsfiddles?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

How can we browse public fiddles?

Comment: Not exactly friendly, but you can do a `site:jsfiddle.net` search in Google. (?)

Comment: @w3dk Ah yes, I forgot about Google. x]

Comment: Otherwise you'd have to generate random strings that match and check to see if they are real URLs or not